# Show div inside other div on hover

Tags: css

I have a div "actions" inside a div which is hidden by default. I want it to show when the mouse hovers over the div. How can I do this?

```
<div class="tile">
  <div class="actions">hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolute basics of CSS … http://jsfiddle.net/SYwjU/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSS:

```
.tile:hover > .actions {
  display:block;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7BbYz/)

Answer (score 1):

Handle it by css

```
.tile:hover .actions{
display:block;
}
```